# What are the main texts of pAshupata shaivism?

Tags: scripture, tradition, manuscripts, pashupata-shaivism

What are the core texts of this sampradaya ?

How many of these are surviving today?

Are there any digitial versions of the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lakulisha's Pashupata Sutra is the main text of Pashupata Shaivism according to the Wikipedia article on Pashupata Shaivism:

> **The Pasupata beliefs are summarized in the Pasaputa Sutra**. This text was rediscovered in 1930 and is attributed to Lakulisa himself. Bhanmdarkar attributes the Atharva-Sirasto the Pasupatas. Also, in the text, their vow is recorded.

You read the Pashupata Sutras (along with Kaundinya's Panchartha Bhashya) in English, [here](https://archive.org/details/PasupataSutramHaripadaChakroborti). Also, you can read it (along with Kaundinya's Panchartha Bhashya) in Sanskrit [here](https://archive.org/details/PasupataSutrasPhotocopy1940ChitrodayaManjariTrivandrumSanskritSeriesCXLIII).